# MSSQL | Joining records that span a date range to a Calendar to distribute the element into the Calendar bins

Tags: t-sql, join, sql-server-2014, date-range

Good day,

**Information:** I have a Calendar table, with a monthly grain. Excerpt:

```
ID StartDate  EndDate    Year Month
1  2000-01-01 2000-01-31 2000 200001
2  2000-02-01 2000-02-29 2000 200002
3  2000-03-01 2000-03-31 2000 200003
4  2000-04-01 2000-04-30 2000 200004
5  2000-05-01 2000-05-31 2000 200005
```

I then have a Task table, where the records comprise of a TaskId, an arbitrary start date, arbitrary end date and a number of attributes. An example excerpt:

```
TaskId Start      End        Attr1 Attr2 Attr3
1      2025-03-13 2026-11-27 1     2     3
2      2027-08-19 2030-02-21 4     5     6
3      2017-06-04 2018-07-30 7     8     9
```

The output I desire is something along the following lines:

```
TaskId Month  Start      End        DaysInPeriod Attr1 Attr2 Attr3
1      202503 2025-03-13 2025-03-31 19           1     2     3
1      202504 2025-04-01 2025-04-30 30           1     2     3
.
.
1      202611 2026-11-01 2026-11-27 27           1     2     3
```

So far, I'm able to get the *start month* and *end month* for each of the tasks, but I'm battling to make the leap of logic required to distribute the tasks across the entire range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
      t.TaskId, 
      c.[Month],  
      CASE WHEN t.Start>c.StartDate THEN t.Start ELSE c.StartDate END as Start,
      CASE WHEN t.[End]<c.EndDate THEN t.[End] ELSE c.EndDate END as [End],

      DATEDIFF(day,CASE WHEN t.Start>c.StartDate 
                        THEN t.Start ELSE c.StartDate END,
                   CASE WHEN t.[End]<c.EndDate 
                        THEN t.[End] ELSE c.EndDate END)
                +1 
                as DaysInPeriod, 
      t.Attr1, 
      t.Attr2,
      t.Attr3

FROM Tasks as t
JOIN calendar as c on 
  c.EndDate BETWEEN t.Start AND t.[End]
  OR c.StartDate BETWEEN t.Start AND t.[End]
  OR t.Start BETWEEN c.StartDate AND c.EndDate
  OR t.[End] BETWEEN c.StartDate AND c.EndDate
```